# Dealing with variable inside awk result division by zero

Tags: shell, awk, fatal-error, division, divide-by-zero

I'm writing a simple shell command using awk, as follow:

```
input_folder='/home/Desktop/files'
results_folder='/home/results'

for entry in $input_folder/*
do

re=$(samtools view -H $entry | grep -P '^@SQ' | cut -f 3 -d ':' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}')

echo -e "$(samtools depth $entry | awk '{sum+=$3} END { print $(sum/$re)}')\t/$entry" >> $results_folder/Results.txt

done
```

the result in variable `re` is a number but using the result of `re` into the second command `print $(sum/$re)}'` give me this error
`awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=312843568) fatal: division by zero attempted`

I tried not to put `$` with the variable but also the same error.

Any help with that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `awk` part to:

```
awk -v re="$re" '{sum+=$3} END { if(re) print sum/re; else print "oo";}'
```

You have to use `-v` to transfer the variable into `awk`.
And also it's better to check if `re` is zero.
I used `oo` to represent `Infinity symbol`.

Comment: IMHO, it could still give error like trying to divide from 0 etc since no check has been performed to check for value of `re` here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Updated. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I didn't assume that, thanks either way :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not clear why you are sending output of `echo` command to `awk`. YOur actual `awk` command should be to avoid your error (in which it tells that you are dividing it by zero). Try changing your `awk` program to following once?

```
awk -v re="$re" '{sum+=$3} END {if(re){print (sum/re)} else {print "Please check seems value of re is ZERO else you will get an error from awk program}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inplacing bash variable into awk will do the job:

```
awk '{sum+=$3} END { print(sum/'${re}') }'
```

You'd better also check ${re} in bash for non zero check before passing to awk.

Comment: IMHO, this will not work in 2 ways. 1st- in `awk` bash variables can't be passed in this manner 2nd there is no condition checked for value of `re` here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Well, you can pass it this way but it's a bad approach :)